# About `native` keyword in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I found a keyword `native` in the Flutter SDK `Window` class.

File path is `//flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/window.dart`.

```dart
void render(Scene scene) native 'Window_render';
```

I can not find any document about the `native` keyword.

How to use it?

What is its meaning?

Answer (score 5):

That seems to be a keyword to call a native library, in order to extend the DartVM functionalities.

You can check [here](https://dart.dev/server/c-interop-native-extensions) for more information!